# System.IO.GetFiles doesn't return files in subfolders even if i use SearchOption.AllDirectories

Tags: vb.net, .net, getfiles

In my code, I use the `GetFiles()-method` to count the number of files inside a given folder

Lets assume the following folderstructure:

```
 FolderA 
          File1
          File2
          File3
          FolderB
                    File4
                    File5
          FolderC
                    File9
                    File10
                    FolderD
                            File6
                            File7
                    FolderE
                            File8
```

To Determine the filecount i use the following code:

```
Dim filename as String = 'Path to my FolderA: C:/....../Desktop/FolderA
Dim myFileCount as Integer = 0
myFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(filename, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length

Result: MyfileCount is 3 instead of 10
```

When executing this code, then the contents of `FolderB` & `FolderC` is not included. Following the [MSDN-Library - GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [MSDN-Library - SearchOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this should work.....

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i tried your code in my environment..IT'S WORKING FOR ME

Comment: Is it possible that the files in the child folders don't have an extension?  Your pattern is `"*.*"` so only files with a dot in the name will match.

Comment: Same here; the code works fine for me. Do you have access rights to FolderB and FolderC?

Comment: All files have the extension .txt or .docx. Rights  aren't an issue (just checked). I have all the rights needed on the folders.

Comment: @MicroVirus You were right! This code is part of an application embedded with Explorer.exe. Apparently it when i build the user sometimes get switched from my User to the 'System'-User (this happens aprox once every 10 builds). This user (System) doesn't have rights on that folder. Right now i just have to search the reason behind that user-switch (which is in its own terms quite strange). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Directory.GetFiles(filename,"*.*",SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories).Length
```

Comment: Same Sarchoption, only different Namespaces: 'SearchAllSubDirectories' comes from Microsoft.Visualbasic.FileIO. 'SearchOption.AllDirectories' comes from 'System.IO'. As i mentionned in the comments, the reason for the failure of an unexcepted Windows-User switch.